# Error in using package “mwe” in Latex

Tags: installing

I am trying to run the following code in Latex, but it gives me this error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `mwe.sty' not found.
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}
\centering
\subfloat[]{\label{main:a}\includegraphics[scale=.5]{plot1.eps}}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}
\centering
\subfloat[]{\label{main:b}\includegraphics[scale=.5]{plot2.eps}}
\end{minipage}\par\medskip
\centering
\subfloat[]{\label{main:c}\includegraphics[scale=.5]{plot3.eps}}
\caption{my fig}
\label{fig:main}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: So you have to install the `mwe` package. Are you using MikTeX?

Comment: No, I am using TexWorks

Comment: I don't know how to install new packages in TeXworks.

Comment: OK, I will search for that. Thank you for letting me know the solution.

Comment: Welcome to the TeX world.

Comment: Texworks is an editor. Not a tex system.  And the mer package is a bundle of example graphics, imho it doesn't contain a sty.

Comment: How about Texmaker?

Comment: Same as Texworks, just an editor. Have you installed MikTeX or TeX Live or (if you're on a Mac) MacTeX? Related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/ (@UlrikeFischer There is actually a `mwe.sty`.)

Comment: I installed MikTeX but I don't know what should I do with that!

Comment: @Sigur, Would you please tell me how should I install this package using MikTex?

Comment: @FerraXu, go to MikTeX options (using the programs menu) and use the Packages Manager. http://docs.miktex.org/manual/images/mpm.png

Comment: @Sigur, Thank you, but package "mwe" is not included in MiKTeX 2.9 packages...How can I add it there?

Comment: You can download it from CTAN http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mwe and install it. See sec 3 of its documentation.

Comment: mwe is a part of miktex. Use the miktex package manager to install it.

Comment: OK I used 'Tex Live 2014' and now it's working! Thank you all!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by installing a missing package, as described in the comments.